# How to generate a Matplotlib plot in a Django web app which can be parametrized using a form

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I'm trying to write a Django web app which displays a plot of a function with several parameters, however I wasn't able to find any examples of this on the web.

So far I've created an `mpl` app within a `mpldjango` project with the following structure:

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── mpl
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
└── mpldjango
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

where `mpl/views.py` is

```
import django
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

def make_canvas(rate):
    rate = float(rate)
    fig = Figure()
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    x = np.arange(-2, 1.5, 0.01)
    y = np.sin(np.exp(rate * x))
    ax.plot(x,y)
    return canvas

def mplimage(request, rate=2):
    canvas = make_canvas(rate=rate)
    response=django.http.HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    return response
```

and `mpldjango/urls.py` is

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import mpl.views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'mplimage.png/a=(?P<rate>[0-9]+)', mpl.views.mplimage),
    url(r'mplimage.png', mpl.views.mplimage),
]
```

Now, after `python manage.py runserver`, if I browse to http://localhost:8000/mplimage.png/a=3, for example, I get the plot with the `rate` parameter set to `3`:

[image]

and similar if I set `a=2` in the URL.

This is not the interface I want however: I would prefer to fill out a form containing plot parameters and have the plot update when I submit it. It seems to me that this would be a very standard code example, but I wasn't able to find any. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I do is that I generate a matplotlib figure, save it as a png to Django `/media` folder configured in your `settings.py` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#media-root and then link it to a page you return instead of the image.